# What kinds of types may an interface type include?

Tags: c#

I have some class type:

```
class MyClass
{
    …
}
```

I wonder whether it is good or bad design to include this type of object in an interface:

```
interface IInterface
{
   List<MyClass> _myobj { get; set; }
}
```

Is it bad practice? Does this mean `IInterface` depends on `MyClass` because I am referencing it from this type?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using custom classes in interfaces. It's a very vague question though.

Comment: relevant http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/250914/why-does-c-allow-properties-in-interfaces

Comment: Just because it is a class you defined doesn't mean you shouldn't use it...never stopped microsoft from using String type properies in their interfaces

Comment: @LoganMurphy Or the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` in `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it bad practice? **NO**. You will do this *all the time*.

Yes, it makes the interface "dependent" on that type, but there is no problem with that. If you need it in the interface, you have a really good chance that they *should* be dependent.

For me, your code is perfectly fine, I wouldn't change a thing except for the weird naming on the property. Properties in C# start with a capital letter, and are camel case from there (otherwise known as *PascalCase*).

Comment: without showing a credible argument against interface properties being a "bad practice", the paragraph to that point is useless if not harmful.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I think the linked question is meaningless. It's not much of an argument in that question -- I see one person _completely_ misunderstanding the interface property syntax, and three answers explaining why he is wrong. It is not really something the OP (or anyone) should know about.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez It wouldn't surprise me if a future reader had heard of it. That said, it isn't remotely vital to my answer. I have removed it, as it seems to distract from my main point.